# PHPExcel, why don't my line breaks appear if using PHPExcel_RichText?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to use PHPExcel to produce something which looks like this:

```
Label:    
This is the value
```

Where "Label" is dark red, and "This is the value" is on a new line, in the same cell.

I've been using the following code:

```
$text = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$label = $text->createTextRun("This is the label: ");
$label->getFont()->setBold(true);
$label->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$label->getFont()->setColor(new PHPExcel_Style_Color(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKRED));

$text->createText(PHP_EOL . "This is the value");

$workbook->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue($text);
$workbook->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

But for some reason this doesn't seem to be working. I've tried "\r" and "\n" in place of PHP_EOL (being careful to use double quotes instead of single ones).

I've also tried moving the PHP_EOL to the label text.

If I call `setValue($text . PHP_EOL)` I lose the formatting, but the line break works.

I'm on a Mac using Excel 2016 if that makes any difference. Unfortunately I'm not able to test on a different version of Excel. Can someone show me how to fix this?

Comment: My advice is dropping PHPExcel and using Spout, that has far better performances https://github.com/box/spout

Comment: Thanks @MassimilianoArione, I'll give this a look

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker, although that is already done in the last line of the code

Comment: Just tested it for the Excel5 and Excel2007 Writers and it works as expected (with Windows version of Excel 2016). What Writer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried your code on my Mac and it works fine but I have already patched several files of the phpExcel package.

I have unzipped the Excel file generated with phpExcel and compared the xml files with those from a regular Excel file and found some differences.
One of them is how bold is specified in the sharedStrings.xml file.
in a phpExcel generated file you have:

```
<b val="1"/>
```

and in a regular Excel file

```
<b/>
```

So in StringTable.php, in writeRichText, I have changed

```
                        // Bold 1
                    if($element->getFont()->getBold())
                    {
                    $objWriter->startElement($prefix.'b');
                    $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', ($element->getFont()->getBold() ? 'true' : 'false'));
                    $objWriter->endElement();
                    }
```

to

```
                        // Bold 1
                    if($element->getFont()->getBold())
                    {
                    $objWriter->startElement($prefix.'b');
                    $objWriter->endElement();
                    }
```

and I did the same for the other true/false properties.

It was not enough to solve my own problem of newlines disappearing in RichTextObjects, but i have given the other patches I've done in [PHPExcel toRichTextObject only showing newlines after saving file again manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470479/phpexcel-torichtextobject-only-showing-newlines-after-saving-file-again-manually).

So that, when I use your code, the newlines are correctly set and visible.
Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the response @Régine. And sorry for the lack of reply - I haven't logged in for a while. In the end it didn't matter because on the Windows version of Excel (the important one according to use case) everything worked as expected in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel for Mac 2011 on latest OS X. Tried to add `PHP_EOL` and/or `"\n"`.

```
$cellValue->createText(PHP_EOL);
$cellValue->createText("\n");
```

Neither is creating a new line when using `PHPExcel_RichText`.